# Alter table to Add default auto increment primary key 'id' in Phinx migration

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, migration, phinx

I had created a table in a Phinx migration using

> ```
> $table = $this->table('verification', ['id' => false, 'primary_key' => ['validation_id']]);
> $table->addColumn('validation_id','string',['limit' => 15, 'null' => false])
>         ->addColumn('status','string', ['null' => true])
>     >create();
> ```

Now in a **separate migration** I want to alter the table and set that id value to true and make that id as primary key (default behaviour). And make validation_id as a unique index.

I know how to do it by dropping the table first and creating new table. But I **don't want to drop the table**, just alter it. How to **alter** table to add back the auto increment default id column?